# Is there way to get a JSON representation of a graph built with arbor.js?

Tags: json, arbor.js

I am building a graph using the [arbor.js](http://arborjs.org) library.

I build my graph using the addNode() and addEdge() functions of arbor.js. And now I would like to retrieve the built graph using something like .toJson() that should be of the following form:

`{nodes:{}, edges:{}}`

where the nodes attribute contains a mapping of node names to data objects. For example,

```
{ nodes:{foo:{color:"red", mass:2},
         bar:{color:"green"}} }
```

and the edges attribute contains nested objects to map source identifier to target, then target to edge data object. e.g,

```
{ edges:{bar:{foo:{similarity:0},
              baz:{similarity:.666}} }
```

Comment: You may want to look the documentation and the source code to find out how the graph data is stored and to decide whether preconversion is needed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the `eachNode`, `eachEdge`, `getNodes` and `getEdges` methods, use those to process the entire graph and create a json object using what those methods return. It does not look like there is a built in method to "traverse the graph and build a json object".